# Controling left margin when dealing with tikz picture, or better yet - centering tikz picture properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins

I have the following tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]


    % % % % % % % % left % % % % % % % %
    \draw (-11.7,0.5) node {$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{f=}}}$};

    % small rectangles
    \draw (-11,0) rectangle (-9,1) node[pos=0.5] {\large$\pi_{S_1}(I)$};
    \draw (-8.6,0.5) node {$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\bowtie}}}$};
    \draw (-8.2,0) rectangle (-6.2,1) node[pos=0.5] {\large$\pi_{S_2}(I)$};
    \draw (-5.8,0.5) node {$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\bowtie}}}$};

    \draw (-4.7,0.5) node {\huge$.\hspace{10pt}.\hspace{10pt}.$};

    \draw (-3.6,0.5) node {$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\bowtie}}}$};

    \draw (-3.2,0) rectangle (-1.2,1) node[pos=0.5] {\large$\pi_{S_n}(I)$};


    % big rectangle
    \draw (-9.5,3) rectangle (-2.7,4) node[pos=0.5] {\large\large\large$I$};

    % arrows
    \draw[<-] (-8.5,2.8) -- (-10,1.2);
    \draw[<-] (-6.5,2.8) -- (-7,1.2);
    \draw[<-] (-3.7,2.8) -- (-2.2,1.2);
    \draw (-10,2) node {$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\beta^{-1}}}$};


    % % % % % % % % right % % % % % % % %
    \draw (1.2,0.5) node {$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{f\,'=}}}$};

    % small rectangles
    \draw (1.9,0) rectangle (3.9,1) node[pos=0.5] {\large$\pi_{S\,'_1}(I\,')$};
    \draw (4.3,0.5) node {$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\bowtie}}}$};
    \draw (4.7,0) rectangle (6.7,1) node[pos=0.5] {\large$\pi_{S\,'_2}(I\,')$};
    \draw (7.1,0.5) node {$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\bowtie}}}$};

    \draw (8.2,0.5) node {\huge$.\hspace{10pt}.\hspace{10pt}.$};

    \draw (9.3,0.5) node {$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\bowtie}}}$};

    \draw (9.7,0) rectangle (11.7,1) node[pos=0.5] {\large$\pi_{S\,'_n}(I\,')$};


    % big rectangle
    \draw (3.4,3) rectangle (10.2,4) node[pos=0.5] {\large\large\large$I\,'$};

    % arrows
    \draw[->] (4.4,2.8) -- (2.9,1.2);
    \draw[->] (6.4,2.8) -- (5.9,1.2);
    \draw[->] (9.2,2.8) -- (10.7,1.2);
    \draw (2.9,2) node {$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\beta}}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

The above produces this:

[image]

As you probably noticed, this is not what I intended when I used the `\begin{center}\end{center}` tags...

Is there a way to force the picture to be centered regardless of the left margin?
In other words, how do I tell the picture to ignore the margin and to center the whole thing properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is unrelated to tikz, `center` essentially puts \hfill space to the side of every line so can not centre things that are wider than textwidth as the minimum width of the glue added on the left is 0pt. put the picture (or anything) in \makebox[0pt]{....} to hide its width

Comment: Using the [remember picture, overlay] option you can use the anchor (current page.center) for the exact center of the page.